# PromQL metric with two labels

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have following prometheus metric:

```
doc_range_size_mb_total{name="userA",range="range_10MB",} 89.0
doc_range_size_mb_total{name="userB",range="range_10MB",} 252.0
doc_range_size_mb_total{name="userB",range="range_1MB",} 849.0
doc_range_size_mb_total{name="userA",range="range_1MB",} 16.0
doc_range_size_mb_total{name="userA",range="range_49MB",} 12.0
doc_range_size_mb_total{name="userB",range="range_100MB",} 2.0
```

and my aim is to get a grafana graphic which shows the amount of files in the different size range grouping by user.
For instance:

```
       Range_1MB   Range_10MB  Range_49MB  Range_100B
UserA     15          89           12
UserB    849         252                      2
```

Currently I have problems to combine the two labels of this one metric to get the wished output.
Any help would be appreciate. :-)

Comment: Can you add code that you have already tried? What is your current output?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I haven't any code which I could share. I am not as familiar with promQL. I have tried many but without any tangible results :-(